# Solving $\int e^{kx}(f(x)+f'(x))\, dx.$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Evaluate: $$\int_1^2 e^{2x}\left(\ln x+\frac1x\right)\, dx.$$ I was trying to put the integrand in the form $e^x(f(x)+f'(x))$ so that it could be integrated easily but a term of the form $\int_1^2\frac{e^u}{u}\, du$ (which will lead to the exponential integral $\operatorname{Ei}(u)$) appeared while doing so.

So I was wondering if there's a way to evaluate the integral without making use of the exponential integral? If yes, please give me some hints. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only when $k=1$, $\int_{a}^{b} e^{x}\left(f(x)+f^{\prime}(x)\right) d x= \int_{a}^{b} d\left(e^{x} f(x)\right) = e^{b} f(b)-e^{a} f(a) $.  Otherwise you will meet the exponential integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_1^2 e^{2x}\Big(\ln x+\frac1x\Big)\, \mathrm dx = \int_1^2 e^{2x}\ln x\,\mathrm dx +\int_1^2 \frac{e^{2x}}x\,\mathrm dx $$

Integrating by parts with $\ln x =u$,

$$\begin{align}\int_1^2 e^{2x}\Big(\ln x+\frac1x\Big)\, \mathrm dx &= \left. \frac12e^{2x}\ln x\right|_1^2 -\frac12\int_1^2 \frac{e^{2x}}x\,\mathrm dx +\int_1^2 \frac{e^{2x}}x\,\mathrm dx \\ &= \frac12e^4\ln2+\frac12\int_1^2\frac{e^{2x}}x\,\mathrm dx \\ &= \frac12e^4\ln2+\frac12\int_2^4\frac{e^u}u\,\mathrm du \\ &= \frac12e^4\ln2 +\frac12[\text{Ei}(4)-\text{Ei}(2)]\end{align}$$

As you can see, no escape from the exponential integral. But, the result can be expressed in the form of the hypergeometric and the Meijer G function.